# No Such element Exception in websphere

Tags: java, stack-trace

I am working on websphere, and the workspace is constantly giving the error "NoSuchElementFound". I am trying to understand the logs(ffdc to be specific) but not able to. Here is the dump of the log file.

```
[12/16/15 5:48:16:847 CST]     FFDC
 Exception:java.util.NoSuchElementException
 SourceId:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters
 -RE ProbeId:1123 Reporter:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManagerImpl@fb2c5c52
java.util.NoSuchElementException    
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)    
    at com.caremark.psd.infrastructure.security2.html.HTMLSecureRenderer.findIpAddress(HTMLSecureRenderer.java:2624)    
    at com.caremark.psd.infrastructure.security2.html.HTMLSecureRenderer.displayMainPage(HTMLSecureRenderer.java:209)   
    at com.caremark.psd.infrastructure.security2.html.HTMLSecureRenderer.renderGet(HTMLSecureRenderer.java:1190)    
    at com.caremark.psd.infrastructure.security2.html.HTMLSecureRenderer.renderPost(HTMLSecureRenderer.java:1429)   
    at com.caremark.psd.infrastructure.security2.html.SecureServlet.doPost(SecureServlet.java:194)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)     
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)     
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1225)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)  
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)

Reporter
BEGIN:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManagerImpl@fb2c5c52
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::_filterWrappers
BEGIN:java.util.Hashtable@83029107  {  } 
END:java.util.Hashtable@83029107

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::chainCache
BEGIN:java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap@a3480b04  {  } 
END:java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap@a3480b04

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::forwardChainCache
BEGIN:java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap@856b889b  {  } 
END:java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap@856b889b

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::includeChainCache
BEGIN:java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap@24cb5df7  {  } 
END:java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap@24cb5df7

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::errorChainCache
BEGIN:java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap@d0d052f7  {  } 
END:java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap@d0d052f7

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::_filtersDefined:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::FMI_MAPPING_SINGLE_SLASH:0
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::FMI_MAPPING_PATH_MATCH:1
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::FMI_MAPPING_EXTENSION_MATCH:2
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::FMI_MAPPING_EXACT_MATCH:3
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::logger:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.logging.WebContainerLogger@9d0923f8
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::CLASS_NAME:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::nls
BEGIN:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS@e7fa1876  com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS::tc
BEGIN:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent@a584146d  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivLevel:10  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivName:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivDebugEnabled:false  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivEventEnabled:false  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivEntryEnabled:false  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivDetailEnabled:false  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivConfigEnabled:false  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivInfoEnabled:true  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivServiceEnabled:true  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivWarningEnabled:true  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivErrorEnabled:true  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivFatalEnabled:true  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::defaultMessageFile:com.ibm.ejs.resources.seriousMessages
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::EXTENSION_NAME_DPID:DiagnosticProvider
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivDumpEnabled:false  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivResourceBundleName:com.ibm.ejs.ras.resources.RasMessages
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivLogger:null  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivDiagnosticProviderID:null  
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::anyTracingEnabled:false  
END:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent@a584146d

 com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS::nullKey:null Key 
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS::svNullBundleName:Resource Bundle name is
null, key = {0}  com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS::svBundleNotLoaded:Unable to
load ResourceBundle {0} 
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS::svNullKeyMessage:Null key passed while using
ResourceBundle {0}  com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS::svMalformedMessage:No
message text associated with key {0} in bundle {1} 
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS::sbConvertMessageIds:false 
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS::svMessageIdPropertyName:com.ibm.websphere.logging.messageId.version
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS::finder:null 
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS::ivBundleName:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.resources.Messages
END:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS@e7fa1876

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::webAppConfig
BEGIN:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfigurationImpl@9cf0f875 
com.ibm.ws.container.BaseConfiguration::_id:LoginWeb.war 
com.ibm.ws.container.BaseConfiguration::_attributes:null 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::CLASS_NAME:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::logger:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.logging.WebContainerLogger@585102ec
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::version:23 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::contextRoot:/clt 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::sessionTimeout:-1 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::moduleSessionTimeoutSet:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::moduleSessionTrackingModeSet:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::sessionCookieConfig
BEGIN:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl@772afd89
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl::comment:  
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl::domain:  
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl::maxAge:-1  
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl::maxAgeSet:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl::name:JSESSIONID
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl::path:/  
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl::httpOnly:true
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl::httpOnlySet:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl::secure:false 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl::secureSet:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl::contextInitialized:true
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl::externalCall:true
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl::programmaticChange:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl::nls:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceNLS@65dabb05
depth limit reached  
END:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl@772afd89

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::hasProgrammaticCookieConfig:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::sessionDefaultTrackingModeSet
BEGIN:java.util.RegularEnumSet@bc8b2cba   {   
javax.servlet.SessionTrackingMode@412b850 depth limit reached   
javax.servlet.SessionTrackingMode@3640dd7c depth limit reached   }  
END:java.util.RegularEnumSet@bc8b2cba

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::sessionManagerConfigBase
BEGIN:com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig@c4d1f9c4  
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionManagerConfigBase::usingWebContainerSM:true
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionManagerConfigBase::useContextRootForSessionCookiePath:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionManagerConfigBase::serverLevelSessionCookieName:JSESSIONID
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionManagerConfigBase::is_zOS:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionManagerConfigBase::sessionIDLength:23
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionManagerConfigBase::trackingModes:java.util.RegularEnumSet@b309969f
depth limit reached  
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionManagerConfigBase::privateSessionCookieName:JSESSIONID
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionManagerConfigBase::privateSessionCookieComment:
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionManagerConfigBase::privateSessionCookieDomain:null
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionManagerConfigBase::privateSessionCookieMaxAge:-1
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionManagerConfigBase::privateSessionCookiePath:/
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionManagerConfigBase::privateSessionCookieSecure:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionManagerConfigBase::privateSessionCookieHttpOnly:true
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionManagerConfigBase::cookieConfig:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.session.SessionCookieConfigImpl@772afd89
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::usingMemory:true  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::usingDatabase:false  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::usingMemToMem:false  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::enableUrlProtocolSwitchRewriting:false
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::privateDcookieName:SSLJSESSION
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::sipSessionCookieName:ibmappid
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::inMemorySize:1000  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::enableOverflow:true  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::sessionInvalidationTime:1800 
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::integrateSec:false  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::throwSecurityExceptionOnGetSessionFalse:true
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::invalidateOnUnauthorizedSessionRequestException:false
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::allowSerializedSessionAccess:false
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::serializedSessionAccessMaxWaitTime:5
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::accessSessionOnTimeout:true  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::JNDIDataSourceName:jdbc/sample
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::sessionDBID:null  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::sessionDBPWD:null  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::rowSize:4  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::tableSpaceName:null  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::usingMultirow:false  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::drsSettings:null  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::enableEOSWrite:false  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::enableManualWrite:false  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::enableTimeBasedWrite:false  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::mPropertyWriterInterval:120  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::writeAllProperties:false  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::scheduledInvalidation:false  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::optimizeCacheIdIncrements:false
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::alwaysEncodeURL:false  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::onlyCheckInCacheDuringPreInvoke:false
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::enableHotFailover:true  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::forceSessionInvalidationMultiple:3
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::persistSessionAfterPassivation:false
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::usingApplicationSessionsAndInvalidateAll:false
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::usingApplicationSessionsAlwaysRetrieve:false
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::forceSessionIdLengthCheck:false
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::securityUserIgnoreCase:false 
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::sessionTableSkipIndexCreation:false
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::checkSessionNewOnIsValidRequest:true
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::useSeparateSessionInvalidatorThreadPool:false
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::sessionInvalidatatorThreadPoolSize:50
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::delayInvalidationAlarmDuringServerStartup:0
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::SIPConvergedHttpPort:80  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::SIPConvergedHttpsPort:443  
com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig::SIPConvergedHostName:localhost
END:com.ibm.ws.session.SessionManagerConfig@c4d1f9c4

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::displayName:LoginWeb
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::description:null 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::reloadInterval:3 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::distributable:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::reloadingEnabled:true
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::serveServletsByClassnameEnabled:true
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::defaultErrorPage:null
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::additionalClassPath:
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::fileServingEnabled:true
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::directoryBrowsingEnabled:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::autoRequestEncoding:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::autoResponseEncoding:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::autoLoadFilters:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::requestListeners:null
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::requestAttributeListeners:null
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::sessionListeners:null
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::localeMap:null 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::moduleName:LoginWeb.war
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::moduleId:null 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::isSyncToThreadEnabled:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::isSystemApp:false 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::ardEnabled:false 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::ardDispatchType:DISABLED
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::listeners
BEGIN:java.util.ArrayList@b7158217   {   }  
END:java.util.ArrayList@b7158217

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::welcomeFileList
BEGIN:java.util.ArrayList@f7c972db   {   index.html   index.htm  
index.jsp   default.html   default.htm   default.jsp   }  
END:java.util.ArrayList@f7c972db

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::servletMappings
BEGIN:java.util.HashMap@1ba6e336   {   key:LoginServlet   
value:java.util.ArrayList@54ad9f54 depth limit reached   }  
END:java.util.HashMap@1ba6e336

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::lastIndexBeforeDeclaredFilters:0
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::filterMappings
BEGIN:java.util.ArrayList@51a1652a   {   }  
END:java.util.ArrayList@51a1652a

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::servletInfo
BEGIN:java.util.HashMap@24a31b7e   {   key:LoginServlet   
value:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletConfigImpl@2910c5d7 depth
limit reached   }   END:java.util.HashMap@24a31b7e

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::filterInfo
BEGIN:java.util.HashMap@3e5f186b   {   }  
END:java.util.HashMap@3e5f186b

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::mimeMappings
BEGIN:java.util.HashMap@8d7b1444   {   }  
END:java.util.HashMap@8d7b1444

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::mimeFilters
BEGIN:java.util.HashMap@7c140ac5   {   }  
END:java.util.HashMap@7c140ac5

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::isMimeFilteringEnabled:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::theWebGroup:null 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::jspAttributes
BEGIN:java.util.HashMap@4e84570f   {   }  
END:java.util.HashMap@4e84570f

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::fileServingAttributes
BEGIN:java.util.HashMap@65f510f1   {   }  
END:java.util.HashMap@65f510f1

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::invokerAttributes
BEGIN:java.util.HashMap@e631f6c7   {   }  
END:java.util.HashMap@e631f6c7

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::contextParams
BEGIN:java.util.HashMap@2eb3f747   {   }  
END:java.util.HashMap@2eb3f747

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::virtualHost:default_host
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::exceptionErrorPages
BEGIN:java.util.HashMap@a56314b2   {   }  
END:java.util.HashMap@a56314b2

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::codeErrorPages
BEGIN:java.util.HashMap@d1af2067   {   }  
END:java.util.HashMap@d1af2067

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::tagLibList
BEGIN:java.util.ArrayList@fc838177   {   }  
END:java.util.ArrayList@fc838177

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::precompileJsps:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::webApp
BEGIN:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl@e3d5d4e5  
com.ibm.ws.container.AbstractContainer::name:Login#LoginWeb.war  
com.ibm.ws.container.AbstractContainer::isAlive:true  
com.ibm.ws.container.AbstractContainer::subElements:null   
com.ibm.ws.container.AbstractContainer::attributes:java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap@606ed9c2
depth limit reached  
com.ibm.ws.container.AbstractContainer::config:null   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.core.BaseContainer::commands:java.util.ArrayList@daf9f06e
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.core.BaseContainer::requestMapper:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.URIMapper@903fdab
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.core.BaseContainer::parent:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl@8b5208cd
depth limit reached  
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::loginProcessor:null  
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::logoutProcessor:null   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::collabHelper:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.CollaboratorHelperImpl@64430e2d
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::envObject:com.ibm.ws.util.WSThreadLocal@ceab6a2c
depth limit reached  
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::orderedLibPaths:null   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::loader:com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@7bb09aee
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::facade:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.facade.ServletContextFacade@f3bbd883
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::features:java.util.ArrayList@f7734c17
depth limit reached  
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::applicationName:Login  
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::config:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfigurationImpl@9cf0f875
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::webExtensionProcessor:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessorImpl@129d4d16
depth limit reached  
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::SUN_CONFIGURE_LISTENER_CLASSNAME:com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::MYFACES_LIFECYCLE_LISTENER_CLASSNAME:org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::JSF_IMPL_ENABLED_PARAM:com.ibm.ws.jsf.JSF_IMPL_ENABLED
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::JSF_IMPL_ENABLED_CUSTOM:Custom 
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::JSF_IMPL_ENABLED_NONE:None   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::staticDocRoot:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.util.DocumentRootUtils@a54854c2
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp::jspDocRoot:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.util.DocumentRootUtils@d5c2dfbd
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::j2eeNameFactory:com.ibm.ejs.csi.J2EENameFactoryImpl@2e7f5f47
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::userTransaction:com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.UserTransactionImpl@aa106354
depth limit reached  
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::logger:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.logging.WebContainerLogger@585102ec
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::CLASS_NAME:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::javaNameSpaceValue:null   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::initializationCollaborators:[Lcom.ibm.ws.webcontainer.spiadapter.collaborator.IInitializationCollaborator;@d2f66675
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::invocationCollaborators:[Lcom.ibm.ws.webcontainer.spiadapter.collaborator.IInvocationCollaborator;@303d927f
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::moduleMetaData:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebModuleMetaDataImpl@f596728b
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::javaColonCtxt:com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot@c243534f
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::webAppCollaboratorConfig:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.collaborator.WebAppCollaboratorConfigImpl@47b5f378
depth limit reached  
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::deployedModule:null   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::webAppCmd:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl@547c2b69
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::activatedMBeanName:javax.management.ObjectName@ad956822
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::annotationHelperManager:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelperManager@ef5c88a0
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::annotationHelper:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.annotation.StubAnnotationHelper@73572e6
depth limit reached   
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::webAppPmiListener:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebAppPmiListener@3a944d15
depth limit reached  
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::VALIDATOR_FACTORY_KEY:javax.faces.validator.beanValidator.ValidatorFactory
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::numberOfOverriddenConfigs:0
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl::increasedForThisWebApp:false
END:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl@e3d5d4e5

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::virtualHostList
BEGIN:java.util.ArrayList@db322b0c   {   *:9080   *:80   *:9443  
*:5060   *:5061   *:443   }   END:java.util.ArrayList@db322b0c

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::appStartupWeight:1
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::moduleStartupWeight:10000
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::metaDataComplete:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::classesToScan
BEGIN:java.util.ArrayList@7d1acc97   {   }  
END:java.util.ArrayList@7d1acc97

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::uriFilterMappingInfos:null
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::servletFilterMappingInfos:null
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::dynamicServletRegistrationMap:null
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::applicationName:Login
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::libBinPathList
BEGIN:java.util.ArrayList@c35c40b1   {   }  
END:java.util.ArrayList@c35c40b1

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::webXmlDefinedListeners
BEGIN:java.util.HashSet@92dabfe1   {   }  
END:java.util.HashSet@92dabfe1

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::disallowAllFileServingProp:null
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfiguration::disallowServeServletsByClassnameProp:null
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfigurationImpl::metaData:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebModuleMetaDataImpl@f596728b
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfigurationImpl::webFragMerger:null
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfigurationImpl::JCDIEnabled:false
END:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfigurationImpl@9cf0f875

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::webApp:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl@e3d5d4e5
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::collabHelper:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.CollaboratorHelperImpl@64430e2d
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::webAppNameSpaceCollab:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppNameSpaceCollaboratorImpl@df41ab70
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::secCollab
BEGIN:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl@d258df4b
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl::securityCollaborator
BEGIN:com.ibm.ws.security.web.NullWebSecurityCollaborator@1ae9f42e   
com.ibm.ws.security.web.NullWebSecurityCollaborator::tc:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent@6ebe9f16
depth limit reached  
END:com.ibm.ws.security.web.NullWebSecurityCollaborator@1ae9f42e

 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl::lock:java.lang.Object@2546f12a
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl::logger:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.logging.WebContainerLogger@18be7d4
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl::CLASS_NAME:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl::_webContextRoot:/clt
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl::_vHostName:default_host
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl::webAppConfig:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppConfigurationImpl@9cf0f875
END:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.collaborator.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl@d258df4b

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::sessionSecurityIntegrationEnabled:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::assumeFilterSuccessOnSecurityError:false
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::_evtSource:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppEventSource@8beee900
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager::defaultComponentMetaData:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.metadata.WebComponentMetaDataImpl@547c2b69
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManagerImpl::logger:com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.logging.WebContainerLogger@9d0923f8
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManagerImpl::CLASS_NAME:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManagerImpl
END:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManagerImpl@fb2c5c52
```

Comment: The error is coming from the `com.caremark.psd.infrastructure.security2.html.HTMLSecureRenderer` class, which is not a WebSphere class.  You'll need to investigate that error yourself or show the relevant code that is failing.

Answer (score 1):

FFDC's are just stack traces with some extra info about the state of the classes involved in the Exception.  They look intimidating, but are mainly detailed info for use by the IBM support team.  The only thing you need to look at in an FFDC is the stack trace.

So, onto the stack trace.  It looks like the exception is coming from your application classes:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException at
java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349) at 
com.caremark.psd.infrastructure.security2.html.HTMLSecureRenderer.findIpAddress(HTMLSecureRenderer.java:2624) at 
com.caremark.psd.infrastructure.security2.html.HTMLSecureRenderer.displayMainPage(HTMLSecureRenderer.java:209) at 
com.caremark.psd.infrastructure.security2.html.HTMLSecureRenderer.renderGet(HTMLSecureRenderer.java:1190) at 
com.caremark.psd.infrastructure.security2.html.HTMLSecureRenderer.renderPost(HTMLSecureRenderer.java:1429) at 
com.caremark.psd.infrastructure.security2.html.SecureServlet.doPost(SecureServlet.java:194) at 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595) at 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) at 
... more stack
```

The issue is coming from the `findIpAddress` in this class `com.caremark.psd.infrastructure.security2.html.HTMLSecureRenderer`.

If you are able to change this code, then you can just debug the failure because there are no more elements in the String that `findIpAddress` is trying to tokenize.

If you cannot change this code because it's some third-party code, then you should open a support ticket with that company.  There is nothing wrong here within WebSphere though.